# How to Live Stream an exist video store in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, live-streaming

I upload a video to S3, use AWS MediaConvert to transcoding then transfer to the end-user using MediaPackage (VOD). And now, I need Live stream a video available in S3.

I know about MediaLive, the document told me the input of MediaLive is Live stream source like Camera or Broadcast Software. I'm not sure MediaLive accepts the source from a video available in S3. 
Please let me know how to solve my problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "stream a video in S3"? Streaming is used for real-time video broadcasts. It is not relevant for files already stored in S3. It isn't "live".

Comment: Sorry for my bad explain. You right to said it isn't "live". "Stream a video from S3" mean I record a video, upload to S3 and I want to create a "fake" live stream at a time in the future with the video above.